# Why does find print a leading './' if no paths are given?

Tags: find

Why is it that `find` prints out a leading `./` to results if no paths are given?

```
$ find
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

What is the reason for not printing out this?

```
$ find
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *reason* why you see this is because the developer of GNU **`find`** *chose* to provide a "reasonable" behavior for **`find`** when no path is given.  In contrast, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) doesn't state that the parameter is optional:

> The **`find`** utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from ***each file specified by path***, evaluating a Boolean expression composed of the primaries described in the OPERANDS section for each file encountered. Each path operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided, including all trailing *`<slash>`* characters; all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the **concatenation** of the current path operand, a *`<slash>`* if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. The relative portion shall contain no dot or dot-dot components, no trailing  characters, and only single *`<slash>`* characters between pathname components.

You can see the difference in the synopsis for each.  [GNU has](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (as is the convention) optional items in square brackets:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...]
       [expression]
```

while POSIX doesn't indicate that it can be optional:

```
find [-H|-L] path... [operand_expression...]
```

In the GNU program, that's done in [`ftsfind.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/ftsfind.c#n627):

```
  if (empty)
    {
      /*
       * We use a temporary variable here because some actions modify
       * the path temporarily.  Hence if we use a string constant,
       * we get a coredump.  The best example of this is if we say
       * "find -printf %H" (note, not "find . -printf %H").
       */
      char defaultpath[2] = ".";
      return find (defaultpath);
    }
```

and a literal **`"."`** is used for simplicity.  So you'll see the same result with

```
find
```

and

```
find .
```

because (and POSIX agrees) the given *path* will be used to prefix the results (see above for **concatenation**).

With a little work, one could determine when the feature was first added; it was present in the [initial creation of "findutils" in 1996](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=c030b5ee33bbec3c93cddc3ca9ebec14c24dbe07) (see `find.c`):

```
+  /* If no paths are given, default to ".".  */
+  for (i = 1; i < argc && strchr ("-!(),", argv[i][0]) == NULL; i++)
+    process_top_path (argv[i]);
+  if (i == 1)
+    process_top_path (".");
+
+  exit (exit_status);
+}
```

From the changelog for find 3.8, this was apparently

```
Sat Dec 15 19:01:12 1990  David J. MacKenzie  (djm at egypt)

        * find.c (main), util.c (usage): Make directory args optional,
        defaulting to "."
```

Answer (score 11):

Usually, one does post-processing of the files and, in that case, there can be a huge advantage to starting the filename with `./`.  In particular, if a file name starts with `-`, a subsequent command could interpret that filename an option.  `./` avoids that.

As an example, consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
--link  --no-clobber
```

Now, imagine how this command would work if the file names were provided without the `./` in front:

```
$ find -type f -exec cp -t ../ {} +
```

We can illustrate the problem with `find` itself.  Let's run it in the same directory as above.  The following works:

```
$ find ./*
./--link
./--no-clobber
```

The following fails:

```
$ find *
find: unknown predicate `--link'
Try 'find --help' for more information.
```

Comment: It makes sense. But then there's the question why it doesn't prepend a '.' when you run `find *`.

Comment: @n.r. Good point.  I expect that it behaves that way for some kind of historical compatibility.  I added to the answer an example of why this is undesirable behavior.

Comment: Some versions of `file` _demand_ the user to give a path (like the BSD find on OS X). So you usually need to explicitly say something like `find . -type f ...`. From there, it's not a big step for some versions of find (like GNU find) to just default to `.` and leave everything else as is.

Comment: The reason for `find *` not showing the `.` is because `*` lists all files and folders, but excludes `.`. Do `echo *` in a directory that contains only one or two files, and you will see that  `.` is not listed. Thus, `find *` operates on each file expanded. It's the same as if you said `find Desktop/` from home directory. You will see output as `Desktop/foo_bar.txt`

Comment: @n.r. Same reason that `find foo` doesn't prepend `./` - it prepends `foo/`

Comment: Fine. But then this doesn't prevent post-processing of `-files` from getting interpreted as flags to `find` itself.

Comment: @Serg: I believe that you’re misinterpreting the OP’s follow-up question. It’s not “Why doesn’t `find *` print `. .. file1 file2 file3`?”; it’s “Why doesn’t `find *` print `./file1 ./file2 ./file3`?”. [immibis](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301570/80216#comment529592_301574) (and [Mrigesh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/301570/80216#301577) and [Thomas Dickey](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/301570/80216#301629)) have answered that question.

Comment: @John1024:  I believe that [Mrigesh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301570/80216#301577) and [Thomas Dickey](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/301570/80216#301629) have correctly answered the question.  This answer states why it’s convenient that `find` behaves the way it does.  Do you have any authoritative reference information to support the implied claim that `find` was designed to behave in this way *for this reason?*

Comment: I understand his follow-up question correctly.  And like i said, it has nothing to do with `find` but with the` *`. Do the thing with`echo *` and you'll see

Comment: Also @G-Man  note that `find *` will print only `file1 file2 file3` . It *will not print* `. .. file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 4):

The `find` command needs path(s) to search. 
If we don't specify any,
it uses the current directory (**`.`**) as its starting point. 
Similarly, if you pass the path, e.g., `/tmp`,
it considers that as its starting point. 
And therefore the results.

If current directory:

```
        $ find
or
        $ find .

output:
        ./file1
        ./file2
        ./file3
```

If `/tmp` directory:

```
        $ find /tmp

output:
        /tmp/file4
        /tmp/file5
```

If `abc` directory under the current directory:

```
        $ find abc

output:
        abc/file6
        abc/file7
```

If multiple directories under the current directory:

```
        $ find fu bar

output:
        fu/file10
        fu/file11
        bar/file8
        bar/file9
```

Comment: Yes, I agree `find` needs a path to search anything and that it defaults to the current directory. The question is why it prints out the leading `./` when `file.txt` is just the same as `./file.txt`.

Comment: its not that find adds "." at start actually it adds whatever you give it as path, whether, it is "/tmp" "abc" or ".". It will return all values respectively.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not specify a path, `find` command assumes the `${PWD}` as the path and prints it out on its output. User not specifying the path doesn't change the way `find` works. And find always works with paths by default.

Comment: I see. But if you execute it under `/tmp`, then `$PWD` is `/tmp` not `./`.

Comment: if you want to see preceeding `/tmp`, run the command `find /tmp` If you do not specify a path it will always be current directory, which is `./`

Comment: It's not that I want to see preceeding `/tmp`. It's that it can't be `$PWD`.

Comment: My apologies `${PWD}` was the incorrect verbiage

Comment: No, it doesn't assume $PWD. Compare the output of `find .`, `find $PWD` and `find` (without a path, if your find supports it).