# On the terminal: in the function find

Tags: find

When i specify user in on the find function on the terminal:
Why do I have to write a `/` before I write -user EXAMPLE?

example:

```
find -user USERNAME
```

won't do anything whereas

```
find / -user USERNAME
```

Work exactly as intended?

P.S:
If I use 2 functions one after the other:

```
find / -user USERNAME -group GROUPNAME
```

Will it find the files that are belong to both user and the group or files that belong to the user or the group?

I tried searching on the documentation for answers and couldn't find anything, where can I find answers for this type of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Linux, you are likely using GNU find.  That supplies a "." (current working directory) if no explicit directory parameter is given.

The `find` utility only shows what it *finds* (does not actually tell you where it is *looking*), so you may not have noticed this.  Apparently there is nothing in (or under) your current working directory owned by *`USERNAME`*, but there is on the computer.  When you gave it a "/" as parameter, `find` searched through the whole computer, starting at the root-level "/".

Regarding

```
find / -user USERNAME -group GROUPNAME
```

`find` treats it as if you said

```
find / \( -user USERNAME -a -group GROUPNAME \)
```

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) explains it like this:

> Conjunction of *primaries*; the ***`AND`*** operator is implied by the juxtaposition of two *primaries* or made explicit by the optional `-a` operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.

In your command, these are *primaries*:

```
-user USERNAME
-group GROUPNAME
```

Further reading:

- [Why does find print a leading './' if no paths are given?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301570/why-does-find-print-a-leading-if-no-paths-are-given/301629#301629)

Answer (score 0):

So, the syntax is

`find (starting directory) (actions and flags)`

So, You need to specify some directory even if it is just the `/` directory. It does not default to `/`

#### Example:

`find /starting_dir -size +500 -atime +20 -print`

This would start in `starting_dir` and look for all files that use 500 blocks or more not accessed in the last 20 days