# Any reason why find does not merge multiple slashes into one?

Tags: find, filenames, standard, compatibility, slash

Is it true that `find` is not supposed to be doing even the most simple path unification/simplifications operations, such as coalescing multiple successive slashes together ([which would be equivalent to the original form](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/117599))?

For example the output of `find .///` is:

```
.///
.///somefile
[…]
```

(tested with `find` from GNU and `busybox`)

If so then why is that? Is there any sensible use case I'm missing? Perhaps for the case that someone is grepping the output of `find` inside scripts?

BTW, Also interesting is the output of GNU's find for `find ./// -maxdepth 0 -printf '%h\n'` (`%h` is supposed to be ["Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element and the slash before it)"](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Name-Directives)): `.//` (simply one fewer `/`)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar

Comment: @JeffSchaller This is about the special case with leading slashes, it's true that this might theoretically make a difference but IMHO it would not justify never merging.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) simply says that the path operand is concatenated with the results, without saying that the concatenation could be simplified.  I used that in a previous answer (this is probably a duplicate).

Comment: Interesting question. I guess you could reverse the question: why would find merge multiple slashes? If, say, I got a script that uses find and it parses a string with multiple strokes / slashes then that may point to a bug in the script. In that case hiding the bug wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @rkhff I feel like it should do so because it acts on paths, has to understand them and it seems to me like it's always good to work with the most simple and clear representation, makes things possibly easier and less buggy.

Comment: @rkhff But now that I think of, it might not be always easy to reach the most simple and unified representation, in that case you would have to define the exact process in the standard and this might be complex. And in the case of e.g. `busybox` code size might also play a role.

Comment: Related: [Is it ok that find displays double forward-slash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320435/is-it-ok-that-find-displays-double-forward-slash) (where the applicable POSIX rule is quoted)

Comment: I probably had this (earlier) one in mind: [301570](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301570/why-does-find-print-a-leading-if-no-paths-are-given/301629#301629).

Comment: You ask what is the usecase, like why did they write some code to do that. They did not. They just did not write extra code to do some thing else e.g. convert `////` to `/`, or `/./././` to `/` or `foo/bar/..` to `foo`. Oh wait, that would be a bug, if bar say a symlink. So we would have to collapse in some cases and not in others. So I will restate the question, why does it not have more complex code to handle with special cases that don't need handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have utilities that can understand NUL characters, then this historical behavior can be used to distinguish between files. The output of find will never contain two slashes in a row unless they are provided as part of the initial path. This means that output like

```
.//path/to/file
./name/more
```

tells you that there is a directory called `file\n.` rather than there is a sub-directory of the current directory called `name` if you invoke find with

```
find .// -print
```